# Symfony Options Resolver allow Invalid Options

Tags: symfony, configuration, components

I am using the optionsResolver component in a silex project to resolve options for configuration. If I don't explicitly set options with `setRequired`, `setOptional`, or `setDefaults` I get an error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\InvalidOptionsException' with message 'The option "option.key" does not exist. Known options are: ...`

I want to allow options that are not defined with those methods. I tried to use my own class that extends the class but the class uses to many private methods that would require me to copy/paste most of the class.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I use this component in [ApiGen](https://github.com/apigen/apigen/blob/3a2184ab569be592d71cb8d8000aad2630742642/src/ApiGen/Configuration/Configuration.php#L104) a I think you can't add options that aren't specified.

If you know all options, it is the best practice to name them all.

What is your specific use case?

Comment: I am building a silex skeleton. I am using it to require/validate some config options but I need to add additional options that are not specified.

Comment: In such case I'd use OptionsResolver only for known config options.

Something like this (not tested):

```php
    $config = array('known' => TRUE, 'unknown' => FALSE);
    $knonwKeys = array('knonw');
    $knonwOptions = array_filter($config, function ($key) { return in_array($key, $knownKeys);, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    $optionsResolver->resolve($knonwOptions);
```

(Probably not possible to write nice code in comments).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating two resolvers. One with the fixed option list, the other is where I add options dynamically. I then split the incoming options array into two arrays using array_filter:

```
$dynamicOptions = array_filter($options, function($k) use ($fixedOptionKeys) {
    if (!in_array($k, $fixedOptionKeys)) {
        return true;
    }
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

$fixedOptions = array_filter($options, function($k) use ($fixedOptionKeys) {
    if (in_array($k, $fixedOptionKeys)) {
        return true;
    }
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution will be more pretty and simplier.
Just create your own optionsResolver that extends the symfony base one and override the 'resolve' method

Hope it will help

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ExtraOptionsResolver extends OptionsResolver
{
    /**
     * Strip options that have been passed to
     * this method to be resolved, and that have not been defined as default or required options
     * The default behaviour is to throw an UndefinedOptionsException
     *
     * @author Seif
     */
    public function resolve(array $options = array())
    {
        // passing by ref in loops is discouraged, we'll make a copy
        $transformedInputOptions = $options;
        foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
            if (!in_array($key, $this->getDefinedOptions())) { // option was not defined
                unset($transformedInputOptions[$key]); // we will eject it from options list
            }
        }

        return parent::resolve($transformedInputOptions);
    }
}
```